# access violation in 3-dimensional array c++(using malloc)

Tags: c++, c, dynamic, malloc

I am trying to make a 3-d integer array where I know the number of columns is 2.
I am initializing the array sequentially using malloc. Please suggest what could be wrong?

```
int **output_vertex[2];
for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    output_vertex[j]= (int **)malloc(sizeof(int **));
output_vertex[1][0]==(int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
output_vertex[1][0][0] =11;
//also tried  *output_vertex[1][0] =11;
```

Comment: sorry.it's not working even if clipcounter is 0.(edited)

Comment: You are just allocating 2 members on output_vertex, but then you are iterating through 4 of them. Why?

Comment: i think that part is working fine.it's breaking at the last line.

Comment: `sizeof(int *)` is the same as `sizeof(int **)` or even `sizeof(int ******)`. I hope it rings a bell!

Comment: You have a "==" on the fourth line where it should be "=".

Comment: thanks.chradcliffe..that was silly :)

Comment: You're also running off the bounds of output_vertex in the for loop. You haven't allocated the top level array. Using three-dimensional arrays like this can be quite error-prone. If you can, I'd suggest making things easier on yourself by using something like [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html).

Comment: @chradcliffe: since he's using malloc vs new, my assumption is that he is using C, instead of C++. Which, unless I'm vastly mistaken, Boost is only for C++.

Comment: @M4rc C++ is in the title and is tagged in the question.

Comment: @chradcliffe Can you please suggest how I could resolve this using same variable as I am not in a situation to revamp my code right now.My aim is to get an array of 5 each of which must be a 2-d integer-array whose rows are not known and columns are 2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what your error is (or which one you'd be referring to). Firstly I don't know why you're statically creating an array and then using malloc. Secondly, I don't understand why you're iterating through your for loop four times (0, 1, 2, 3). Shouldn't your allocation be something like this:

```
int **output_vertex;
output_vertex = (int **)malloc(2*(sizeof(int **)));
```

Comment: i couldn't follow you.In your code you are declating a 2d array.I wanna declare a 3d array

Comment: Can you please suggest how I could resolve this .My aim is to get an array of 5 each of which must be a 2-d integer-array whose rows are not known and columns are 2

Answer (score 1):

The array declaration you have is not what you intended. You have a two-element array of pointers to pointers to int. [This page](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) is a good guide to reading those declarations.

Personally, I prefer to use typedefs and build a complex type like this from the ground up:

```
typedef int[2] element_type; // this is the 2-element array of ints
typedef element_type* inner_type; // this is the array of unknown size
typedef inner_type[5] outer_type; // this is the actual type we want to use

outer_type output_vertex; // we now have an array of 5 inner_type variables on the stack
// The output_vertex is *uninitialized* so we have to initialize each of its elements
for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
    output_vertex[i] = new inner_type[SOME_SIZE];
}
// do stuff with output_vertex now that it's initialized
// then, to prevent memory leaks, delete the memory you allocated
for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
    delete[] output_vertex[i];
}
```

There are probably ways to simplify, but that should be a start.

If you want the `inner_type` to be appendable, I would *strongly* recommend using `std::vector` instead of raw arrays. There is far much bookkeeping to be done with raw arrays, so I won't give an example of that; however, here's more-or-less what you would do with `std::vector`:

```
typedef std::pair<int,int> element_type; // this is the 2-element array of ints as a pair
typedef std::vector<element_type> inner_type; // dynamic vector this time

inner_type output_vertex[5]; // we now have an array of 5 inner_type variables on the stack
// do stuff with output_vertex
```

`std::vector` is just as fast as a dynamically-allocated array, but you don't have to do any of the bookkeeping yourself. You also have the benefit of not needing to manage as many heap-allocated objects.

Note that raw arrays aren't compatible with containers (e.g. `std::vector`), so I use `std::pair` here instead.

If you're able to use C++11 (or boost) and you need a fixed-size array of greater than two items that can fit into a standard container, use `std::array`.

Comment: Thanks.What if I don't know the size of "inner_type" and I only know whenever I want to add a new element to "inner_type".